# Gradient exploding problem in a graph neural network

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I have a gradient exploding problem which I couldn't solve after trying for several days. I implemented a custom message passing graph neural network in tensorflow which is used to predict a continuous value from graph data. Each graph is associated with one target value. Each node of a graph is represented by a node attribute vector, and the edges between nodes are represented by an edge attribute vector.

Within a message passing layer, node attributes are updated in a certain way (e.g. by aggregating other node/edge attributes), and these updated node attributes are returned.

Now, I managed to figure out where the gradient problem occurs in my code. I have the below snippet.

```
to_concat = [neighbors_mean, e]
z = K.concatenate(to_concat, axis=-1)
output = self.Net(z)
```

Here, `neighbors_mean` is the element-wise mean between two node attributes `vi`, `vj` that form the edge having an edge attribute `e`. `Net` is a single layer feed-forward network. With this, the training loss suddenly jumps to NaN after about 30 epochs with a batch size of 32. If the batch size is 128, still the gradients explode after about 200 epochs.

I found that, in this case, the gradients explode because of the edge attribute `e`. If I didn't concatenate `neighbors_mean` with `e` and just used the below code, there would be no gradient explosion.

```
output = self.Net(neighbors_mean)
```

Also I can avoid gradient explosion by sending `e` through a sigmoid function as follows. But this degrades the performance (final MAE), because the values in `e` are mapped to 0-1 range non-linearly. Note that ReLU instead of sigmoid didn't work.

```
to_concat = [neighbors_mean, tf.math.sigmoid(e)]
z = K.concatenate(to_concat, axis=-1)
output = self.Net(z)
```

Just to mention that `e` carries a single value relating to the distance between the two corresponding nodes and this distance is always in the range 0.5-4. There are no large values or NaNs in `e`.

I have a custom loss function to train this model, but I found that this is not a problem with loss (other losses also led to the same problem). Below is my custom loss function. Note that although this is a single output regression network, the final layer of my NN has 2 neurons, relating to the mean and log(sigma) of the prediction.

```
def robust_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  """
  Computes the robust loss between labels and predictions.
  """
  mean, sigma = tf.split(y_pred, 2, axis=-1)
  # tried limiting 'sigma' with  sigma = tf.clip_by_value(sigma,-4,1.0) but the gradients still explode
  loss =  np.sqrt(2.0) * K.abs(mean - y_true) * K.exp(-sigma)  + sigma
  return K.mean(loss)
```

I basically tried everything suggested online to avoid gradient explosion.

1. Applied gradient clipping - with `Adam(lr, clipnorm=1, clipvalue=5)` and also with `tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 1.0)`
2. My target variables are always scaled
3. Weights are initialized with `glorot_uniform` distribution
4. Applied regularisation to weights
5. Tried larger batch sizes (till 256, although delayed gradient explosion happens at some point)
6. Tried with reduced learning rate

What am I missing here? I definitely know it has something to do with concatenating `e`. But given that 0.5<e<4, why do the gradients explode in this case? This feature `e` is important to me. What else can I do to avoid numerical overflow in my model?

(Posting here as I did not get an answer to this question on SO)